# Validation plugin - ajax call for messages

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using 1.9.0 jquery version, and this validation plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

I want to download messages in JSON format from the PHP file like this:

```
    messages: {
        remote: function() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/My/index.php/form/validate/messages',
                type: "POST",
                }).done(function(messages) {
                    return messages;
                }
            );
         }
    }
```

However, it doesn't work at all, doesn't display messages, makes ajax calls, nothing. Could you help me with this one?

Comment: You should post your relavent PHP code as this will help with providing you an answer – also added PHP tag.

Comment: Also adding the failed method to the ajax request like so .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.info(errorThrown);} after your done call, then use chrome console to see the output will give you a better understanding of the error similar to @Norbert Pisz

Comment: Also as you are using the 1.9 version are you also running the jquery migrate plugin as this might be abel to assist you and if the validation plugin has not been updated to the latest version of jquery then it might be the plug in itself, just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/My/index.php/form/validate/messages',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (results) {
            //your data here in results
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("error");
        }
    });
```

When display "error" something is wrong on ServerSide. You need to debug it. You can use Firebug Network Console to check results or Network Console in browser.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `remote` rule, see the documentation for examples:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

The `remote` rule is used to compare the contents of a particular field with your database... like checking if a name or password already exists.  It **cannot** be used to simply dump a list of error messages back into the plugin.  As far as the plugin is concerned, you are only setting the one error message for the one rule.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/zga8y/

I really don't understand the purpose of what you're trying to do.  Typically the error messages for each rule are set once and do not change.

To *dynamically* change the message on a particular field, you could use [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).  You don't even have to touch the rules to over-ride the messages.

```
$("#myinput").rules("add", {
    messages: {
        required: "Required input",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can over-ride any or all messages like this:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "This field is required.",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});
```